# Check for new file and convert to dds

Tags: powershell, imagemagick

I have a folder in which jpgs are created. When a new JPG is created, I need to resize it (to 2048x2048 pixels for instance) and convert it to a .dds (dxt1). All of this automatically.

I started to Google batch file commands, then understood that it would probably be better to use powershell and found out about ImageMagick converter. But I'm not sure of any of this and don't know where to begin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert on Windows BATCH, but you can do something along these lines. Save the following code as `JPG2DDS.BAT` and run it using

```
JPG2DDS
```

or by double-clicking it.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Start of infinite loop monitoring directory for JPGs
:TOP
   echo Checking for files...
   REM Work through all JPEG files converting to DDS
   FOR /F %%f IN ( 'DIR /B *.JPG' ) DO (
      ECHO Processing file %%f...
      convert "%%f" -resize 2048x2048 "%%f.dds"
      REM If it worked, rename the original file so we don't do it again
      REM If it didn't work, we'll try again next time round
      IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
         ECHO Conversion successful
         REN "%%f" "%%f.converted"
      )
   )   
   REM Sleep so as not to overload Windows
   ECHO Sleeping...
   SLEEP 10
GOTO TOP
```

All the commands above are described with examples [here](http://ss64.com/nt/).

The `convert` command is part of **ImageMagick** which you will need to install. Before you run this script, make sure that you can convert a single JPEG to DDS using a command like this:

```
convert someImage.jpg -resize 2048x2048 result.dds
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to get my hands dirty but I still don't get much so I think I'm gonna ask for some friend to teach me a bit.